# Is it possible to make mysql order by index prefix?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

If I create an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
```

Is it possible to make MySQL use it for ordering in a query like

```
SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY .... ?
```

Comment: what do you mean by `part_of_name` ?

Comment: The statement shown here creates the index "part_of_name" using the first 10 characters of the name column

Answer (score 0):

No, we can not create indexes based on a part of column's name. It is not allowed and we can not use it in anyway.

To create and use an index, we can only do it based on one table column or more.

[Documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Mary wasn't talking about "part of a column's name" but about a "part of the _value_ in the column" - which *is* possible using `name(10)` (which only indexes the first 10 characters)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, please, write her answer through her comment.